# IOS: custom transition for a viewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, transition

I have this code in my app to do a transition for a viewcontroller

```
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:second.view];
    [second.view setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480)];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.40]; //the double represents seconds
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [second.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

and it work fine;
but inside second view controller I have this code to disappear this viewcontroller

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.40]; //the double represents seconds
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 480)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

it work fine, but what's the way to release it, where can I release this second that I alloc when I call it??
if I write [self.view removeFromSuperView]?? is it released??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove it from the superView then release the SecondViewController that you allocated in your code.

```
SecondViewController *second = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
```

So since you are owning this object you need to release it.
So somewhere after hiding the second view, and removing it from superView, you need to release it...

```
[second release];
```

Comment: but I don't understand where I can release it... because if I release it when I show second with first animation, when I close it it say me taht it's a deallocated...

Comment: You need to release the controller after you hide the second view (the view of the controller)

Comment: ok...for example in viewwillappear of firstviewcontroller...no?

Comment: You need to release it AFTER hiding the second View! Not after showing the view, because else if you have any buttons/actions in the second view, they will crash your app (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)